# If there is no data I want to show EmptyList

Tags: android, simpleadapter

I have Simple Adapter With Array List so on my list view I having two buttons for Next Date and Previous Date display date in text view. So when I click on next date like 19-06-2016 so whatever data is associate with this date displaying  in list view same for next date means for 20-06-2016 but I have problem with it if there is no data on 21-06-2016 in my list view showing previous date's data but in that case list view should be empty but in my list view it is taking same data which is associated with 20-06-2016 which is I don't want. 
I also used `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(),adapter.notifyDataSetInvalidated();` for that but it didnt work.

```
lstViw = (ListView) getView().findViewById(R.id.sSlst);
                adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                        getActivity(), ssLst,
                        R.layout.surgerysch_item, new String[]{
                        TAG_SIMRDNO, TAG_SIPNME, TAG_SISEX,
                        TAG_SIDOB, TAG_SIPROC, TAG_SIOTNME,
                        TAG_SIOTME, TAG_DRNAME}, new int[]{R.id.txtsimrdNo,
                        R.id.txtsiptnNme, R.id.txtsiSex,
                        R.id.txtsiDob, R.id.txtsiProc,
                        R.id.txtsiotNme, R.id.txtsiotTme, R.id.txtDrnme});

                lstViw.setAdapter(adapter);

                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                adapter.notifyDataSetInvalidated();`
```

Comment: add always your code with your problem .

Comment: without code, it is impossible to find out what the silly mistake you did ...

Comment: bro its not about prediction , every person mind is different . Istead of comment just put some code, which is look like a problem.